# Descarga de archivo desde dirección Blob usando Python

Tags: python-3.x, blob

Estoy intentando descargar automáticamente mediante un script en Python un archivo dentro de una página web. Concretamente dentro de esta https://www.ishares.com/us/products/etf-investments#!type=ishares&style=All&view=keyFacts

Para descargar el archivo manualmente hay que pulsar en **Download** y luego en **Download results(xls)**. Inspeccionando la página he conseguido dar con la dirección a la que redirige la etiqueta y es una url con **blob** al principio. No se como manejar dicho archivo ni si hay forma de descargarlo automáticamente mediante el script.

He probado a hacerlo tanto con wget como con request pero he sido incapaz de hacerlo funcionar.

Cualquier sugerencia me sería de ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente usa el módulo `request` y pásale la dirección URL de **Download results(xls)** te dejo como sería:

```
import requests

url_excel= "https://direccion_aleatoria.com/excel_aleatorio.xlsx"

#le pasamos la url a obtener
resp = requests.get(url_excel)

#abrimos la carpeta donde queremos guardar, y guardamos el fichero
output = open('fichero_donde_quieres_guardar/excel_cualquiera.xls', 'wb')
output.write(resp.content)
output.close()
```

Comment: Como comento ya intenté realizarlo de esta manera pero me devuelve siempre el mismo error gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

Comment: Ahh, pedona pues lo siento pero no puedo ayudarte :( he leido por internet que tiene que ver con el Proxy, pero no tengo más conocimientos sobre ello. Lo siento.

Comment: No te preocupes, muchas gracias igualmente por tu ayuda :)